# My basic server program cannot find .readLine() while assiging a String variable

Tags: java, import, readline

Keeps throwing out the cannot find symbol for .readLine I have tried variouse declaration and assignment patterns and have used multiple diffrent import statements.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.DataInputStream ;

public class Server {
    public static void main (String [] args)throws IOException {

    ServerSocket servSock = new ServerSocket (8765);
    System.out.println("Waiting for connection... ");
    Socket sock = servSock.accept();

System.out.println("Connection established with client" 
                    + sock.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName());

Scanner inFromClient = new Scanner
    (new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

PrintWriter outToClient = new PrintWriter 
    (new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()), true);

String filename  = inFromClient.readLine();
```

I have try and catch after this.

Answer (score 2):

When using scanners, the method is called `.nextLine()`

So instead of saying `inFromClient.readLine()`, say `inFromClient.nextLine()`

Answer (score 2):

Your imports are good.

But `readLine()` is a `BufferedReader` method and `nextLine()` is a `Scanner` method.
I think that you mixed both.

If you want to use a `Scanner` : use  `nextLine()` to read a line.